# Django, как получить коды ошибок из не валидной формы?

Tags: django

Форма:

```
   class UserForm(forms.Form):
        about = forms.CharField(max_length=123, error_messages={'max_length': 'переполнено'})
```

так

```
f = UserForm({'about':'12345'})
f['about'].errors
f.errors['about'] #или так
```

получаю сообщение (переполнено), но я хочу получить код (max_length). Можно ли это сделать в django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда!

вот это

```
form['about'].errors.as_data()
```

выводит список валидаторов, берем первый, так как он у Вас один, и смотрим его код

```
form['about'].errors.as_data()[0].code
```

[дока](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/)